# Setting up Leaflet with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, leaflet

I am attempting to get leaflet setup in my rails application properly, and I am having some trouble. I am following the steps outlined here [Github Leaflet Repo](https://github.com/axyjo/leaflet-rails). I have done the trivial stuff at the top and am now under the Headers heading.

I am using OpenStreetMaps, so my leaflet.rb file looks like this. (I had to create this file myself as it did not already exist)

```
Leaflet.tile_layer = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
Leaflet.attribution = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'
Leaflet.max_zoom = 18
```

Now the view I am trying to insert the leaflet map in currently looks like this.

```
<% provide(:title, 'Map') %>
<h1>Map</h1>
<div id="map"><%

    map(:center => {
    :latlng => [51.52238797921441, -0.08366235665359283],
    :zoom => 18
    })

%>
</div>
<p>Find me in app/views/dynamic_pages/map.html.erb</p>
```

When I fire up my rails server, there is just the empty space in the div i.e. no map. The div is setup with a height of 500px in my css file if that makes any difference, which I don't think it does.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure you figured this out by now... But in case anyone else is stuck.  [Leaflet-rails documentation](https://github.com/axyjo/leaflet-rails) leaves out the details on how this happens, but the map helper *is* available in the views.  It must be in `<%= %>` tags to display; the problem above is that the erb tag is missing the `=` it should look like this,

```
<div id="map">
  <%=
    map(:center => {
      :latlng => [51.52238797921441, -0.08366235665359283],
      :zoom => 18
    })
  %>
</div>
```

As a side note, `=` in the erb tag tells the interpreter that the following code is an expression meant to be returned as a string to the document. An erb tage without the `=` like this `<% %>` will evaluate the code, but will not try to return it.  For more see [this](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/) blog post for more.